# Frullani integral with multiplication

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, fractions

The integral is this one:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)\cos(bx)}{x}\, dx$$

I tried to convert them to $\sin(ax+bx)-\sin(ax-bx)$ but that doesn't help so much.Somehow I must get a sum but I need a small hint for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2\sin (ax)\cos (bx)=\sin ( (b+a)x)-\sin ((b-a)x) $ . You can set $b+a=A, b-a=B $ and use the theorem.

Comment: from where you got the formula ?

Comment: $\sin (c)-\sin (d)=2\cos (\frac {c+d}{2})\sin (\frac {c-d}{2}) $

Comment: I got it now,thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

> $$\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  } \frac { \sin  \left( ax+ab \right)  }{ x } \, dx=\frac { \pi  }{ 2 } { sgn }(a+b)\\ $$

Comment: is sin (ax+bx)? sgn functions returns the positive value of a+b ?

Comment: sorry,I didn't understand your question.you can look here either https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877212/implied-limits-in-a-frullani-integral

Answer (score 1):

Well, we can use the Laplace transform:

$$\text{f}\left(x\right):=\frac{\sin\left(\text{a}x\right)\cdot\cos\left(\text{b}x\right)}{x}\tag1$$

So, we get:

$$\text{F}_{\text{a},\text{b}}\left(\text{s}\right):=\mathscr{L}_x\left[\frac{\sin\left(\text{a}x\right)\cdot\cos\left(\text{b}x\right)}{x}\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}:=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\text{a}x\right)\cdot\cos\left(\text{b}x\right)}{x}\cdot e^{-\text{s}x}\space\text{d}x\tag2$$

Now, using the '[frequency-domain integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems)' property of the Laplace transform:

$$\text{F}_{\text{a},\text{b}}\left(\text{s}\right)=\int_\text{s}^\infty\mathscr{L}_x\left[\sin\left(\text{a}x\right)\cdot\cos\left(\text{b}x\right)\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}\space\text{d}\sigma\tag3$$

We need to use:

$$\sin\left(\text{a}x\right)\cdot\cos\left(\text{b}x\right)=\frac{\sin\left(x\cdot\left(\text{a}-\text{b}\right)\right)+\sin\left(x\cdot\left(\text{a}+\text{b}\right)\right)}{2}\tag4$$

So, for [the Laplace transform of the $\sin$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms) we get:

$$\mathscr{L}_x\left[\sin\left(\text{a}x\right)\cdot\cos\left(\text{b}x\right)\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}=\mathscr{L}_x\left[\frac{\sin\left(x\cdot\left(\text{a}-\text{b}\right)\right)+\sin\left(x\cdot\left(\text{a}+\text{b}\right)\right)}{2}\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left\{\mathscr{L}_x\left[\sin\left(x\cdot\left(\text{a}-\text{b}\right)\right)\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}+\mathscr{L}_x\left[\sin\left(x\cdot\left(\text{a}+\text{b}\right)\right)\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}\right\}=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left\{\frac{\text{a}-\text{b}}{\sigma^2+\left(\text{a}-\text{b}\right)^2}+\frac{\text{a}+\text{b}}{\sigma^2+\left(\text{a}+\text{b}\right)^2}\right\}\tag5$$

So, for the integral we get:

$$\text{F}_{\text{a},\text{b}}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\int_\text{s}^\infty\left\{\frac{\text{a}-\text{b}}{\sigma^2+\left(\text{a}-\text{b}\right)^2}+\frac{\text{a}+\text{b}}{\sigma^2+\left(\text{a}+\text{b}\right)^2}\right\}\space\text{d}\sigma=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\lim_{\text{n}\to\infty}\left[\arctan\left(\frac{\sigma}{\text{a}-\text{b}}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{\sigma}{\text{a}+\text{b}}\right)\right]_\text{s}^\text{n}\tag6$$

When $\text{a}-\text{b}>0$ we can simplify further:

$$\text{F}_{\text{a},\text{b}}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\pi-\arctan\left(\frac{\text{s}}{\text{a}-\text{b}}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{\text{s}}{\text{a}+\text{b}}\right)}{2}\tag7$$

> Now, when $\text{s}=0$ and $\text{a}-\text{b}>0$:
>
> $$\text{F}_{\text{a},\text{b}}\left(0\right)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\text{a}x\right)\cdot\cos\left(\text{b}x\right)}{x}\cdot e^{-0\cdot x}\space\text{d}x=$$
> $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\text{a}x\right)\cdot\cos\left(\text{b}x\right)}{x}\space\text{d}x=\frac{\pi-\arctan\left(\frac{0}{\text{a}-\text{b}}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{0}{\text{a}+\text{b}}\right)}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}\tag8$$

Comment: Thanks,is very well explained even if it has 8 steps

Comment: @O.Rares You're welcome, I am glad that I could help. If you have questions leave them here!

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the [Frullani theorem for complex parameters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807410/frullani-s-theorem-in-a-complex-context) and get $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(ax\right)\cos\left(bx\right)}{x}dx=\frac{i}{4}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ix\left(a+b\right)}+e^{-ix\left(a-b\right)}-e^{ix\left(a-b\right)}-e^{ix\left(a+b\right)}}{x}dx$$ $$=\frac{i}{4}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ix\left(a+b\right)}-e^{ix\left(a+b\right)}}{x}dx+\frac{i}{4}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ix\left(a-b\right)}-e^{ix\left(a-b\right)}}{x}dx$$ $$=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^{+}}\left(\frac{i}{4}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\epsilon-ix\left(a+b\right)}-e^{\epsilon+ix\left(a+b\right)}}{x}dx+\frac{i}{4}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\epsilon-ix\left(a-b\right)}-e^{\epsilon+ix\left(a-b\right)}}{x}dx\right)$$ $$=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^{+}}\frac{i}{4}\left(\log\left(\frac{\epsilon-i\left(a+b\right)}{\epsilon+i\left(a+b\right)}\right)+\log\left(\frac{\epsilon-i\left(a-b\right)}{\epsilon+i\left(a-b\right)}\right)\right)$$ $$=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}\left(\textrm{sign}\left(a+b\right)+\textrm{sign}\left(a-b\right)\right)}.$$