# Can I solve this using Complex integration?

Tags: complex-integration

I am trying to solve this question.

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}dx$$

As this function $f(x) =\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2} $ has a removable singularity at $z =  0$.Is it possible to solve this using complex integration.If not why ?

Other solutions to this problem are in :
[Find the principal value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057049/find-the-principal-value-of-int-infty-infty-frac1-cos-xx2-mathr)

Thanks

Comment: Here the same problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970612/how-to-integrate-this-improper-integral/1970641#1970641 with you desired solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrate $$f(z)=\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2}$$ over the contour $\gamma$ shown below.

[image]

where the circles are centered at $0$, line segments lie on the real line, the small circle has radius $r$,  the large circle has radius $R$. We consider the limiting case when $R\to+\infty, r\to 0$.

Contribution of the small circle is
$$
-\pi i\,\text{Res}(f,0)=-\pi i(-i)=-\pi
$$
On the large circle we have
$$
|f(z)|=O(R^{-2})\implies \Big{|}\int_{\text{large circle}}f(z)dz\Big{|}=O(R^{-1})\implies\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\text{large circle}}f(z)\,dz=0
$$
Contribution of the real line is
$$
\text{p.v. }\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1-e^{ix}}{x^2}\,dx
$$
By residue theorem
$$
\text{p.v. }\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1-e^{ix}}{x^2}\,dx-\pi=0
$$
Equating real parts we see
$$
\text{p.v. }\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\,dx=\pi
$$
Noting that the integrand is an even function we see
$$
\text{p.v. }\int_{0}^\infty\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$