# How to compute $\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_{-A}^A {\sin(x)e^{itx}\over x} \, dx$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

for $t\in R$, how to compute

> $$\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_{-A}^A {\sin(x) e^{itx} \over x}dx.$$

Is there some way to compute this integral? I am trying to use complex analysis to compute it, but still don't know how to do it.

Comment: Better to use Fourier inversion...

Comment: Differentiate wrt $t$.

Comment: @martycohen: then the integral doesn't converge.

Comment: Use exponential representation of $\sin(x)$. Close contour with upper/lower half-circle depending on inequlities $t+1>0$ and $t-1>0$, now you have pole at z=0 it is lying on the contour, so you should take half of the residue at that point, and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working in the Principal Value sense, since $\frac{\sin(x)\sin(tx)}x$ is odd, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(x)e^{itx}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(x)\cos(tx)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin((t+1)x)-\sin((t-1)x)}{2x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\[3pt]
&=\frac\pi2\left[\operatorname{sgn}(t+1)-\operatorname{sgn}(t-1)\right]\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
The last step in $(1)$ is due to the fact that the following is odd in $t$ and independent of $t$ for $t\gt0$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(tx)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2a}\\
&=\int_{-\infty-i}^{\infty-i}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2b}\\
&=\int_{-\infty-i}^{\infty-i}\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2ix}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2c}\\
&=\int_{\gamma_U}\frac{e^{ix}}{2ix}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_{\gamma_L}\frac{e^{-ix}}{2ix}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2d}\\[6pt]
&=\pi-0\tag{2e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: when $t\gt0$, substitute $x\mapsto x/t$
$\text{(2b)}$: no singularities in $[-R,R]\cup[R,R-i]\cup[R-i,-R-i]\cup[-R-i,-R]$
$\text{(2c)}$: $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$
$\text{(2d)}$: the integral along the curved parts vanishes
$\phantom{\text{(2d)}: }\gamma_U=[-R-i,R-i]\cup Re^{i[0,\pi]}-i$
$\phantom{\text{(2d)}: }\gamma_L=[-R-i,R-i]\cup Re^{-i[0,\pi]}-i$
$\text{(2e)}$: $\gamma_U$ contains a singularity and $\gamma_L$ does not

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{-A}^{A}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{itx}\,dx &=& \int_{0}^{A}\frac{\sin x}{x}\left(e^{itx}+e^{-itx}\right)dx = \int_{0}^{A}\frac{2\sin(x)\cos(tx)}{x}\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{A}\frac{\sin((1-t)x)}{x}\,dx+\int_{0}^{A}\frac{\sin((1+t)x)}{x}\,dx\tag{1}\end{eqnarray*}$$
So, once you prove that
$$ \lim_{A\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{A}\frac{\sin(\beta x)}{x}\,dx =\frac{\pi}{2}\text{Sign}(\beta)\tag{2} $$
(for instance, by exploiting the parity of the integrand function and the residue theorem)
 you have that

$$ \lim_{A\to +\infty}\int_{-A}^{A}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{itx}\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\text{Sign}(1-t)+\text{Sign}(1+t)\right)}\tag{3} $$
where the RHS is a function of the $t$ variable supported on the interval $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $$\begin{align}I\left(t\right)=
  & \lim_{A\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-A}^{A}\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}e^{itx}dx=\frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right)\left(e^{itx}+e^{-itx}\right)}{x}dx
  \\=
 &\frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix\left(1+t\right)}+e^{ix\left(1-t\right)}-e^{-ix\left(1-t\right)}-e^{-ix\left(1+t\right)}}{x}dx
  \\ =
 & \frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix\left(1+t\right)}-e^{-ix\left(1+t\right)}}{x}dx+\frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix\left(1-t\right)}-e^{-ix\left(1-t\right)}}{x}dx
  \\=
  & \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^{+}}\left(\frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\epsilon+ix\left(1+t\right)}-e^{\epsilon-ix\left(1+t\right)}}{x}dx+\frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\epsilon+ix\left(1-t\right)}-e^{\epsilon-ix\left(1-t\right)}}{x}dx\right)
 \end{align} $$ so using the [Frullani's theorem for complex parameters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807410/frullani-s-theorem-in-a-complex-context) we get $$\begin{align}I\left(t\right)=
 & \frac{1}{2i}\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^{+}}\log\left(\frac{\epsilon+i\left(1+t\right)}{\epsilon-i\left(1+t\right)}\right)+\frac{1}{2i}\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^{+}}\log\left(\frac{\epsilon+i\left(1-t\right)}{\epsilon-i\left(1-t\right)}\right)
  \\ =
 & \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\textrm{sgn}\left(1+t\right)+\textrm{sgn}\left(1-t\right)\right)}. 
\end{align} $$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{\infty}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x}\expo{\ic tx} \over x}\,\dd x}
& =
\int_{\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic tx}\
\overbrace{\half\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{-\ic kx}\,\dd k}
^{\ds{\sin\pars{x} \over x}}\
\,\dd x =
\pi\int_{-1}^{1}\ \overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\expo{-\ic\pars{k - t}}\,{\dd x \over 2\pi}}^{\ds{\delta\pars{k - t}}}\
\,\dd k
\\[5mm] & =
\pi\int_{-1}^{1}\delta\pars{k - t}\,\dd k =
\color{#f00}{\pi\bracks{\vphantom{\large A}\verts{t} < 1}}\qquad
\pars{~\bracks{\cdots}:\ Iverson\ Bracket~}
\\[5mm] & =
\color{#f00}{\left\{\begin{array}{rcc}
\ds{\pi} & \mbox{if} & \ds{-1 < t < 1}
\\[2mm]
\ds{0} & \mbox{if} & \ds{\verts{t} > 1}
\end{array}\right.}
\end{align}