# Prove a integral equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, integral-equations

if $x > 0$, show that

$$f(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(xt)}{1+t^2} \, dt= \frac{\pi}{2}e^{-x}$$

The problem appears in the book [Differential Equations: With Applications and Historical Notes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1498702597), under the chapter derivative and integral of Laplace transformation. So I tried to apply the equation

$$\int_0^\infty \frac {f(t)} t \, dt = \int_0^\infty F(p)\,dp,$$

where $F(p) = L[f(x)](p)$, the Laplace transformation of $f(t)$. However, I failed to manipulate the expression to apply this equality.

I need your help. Please not be misled by my approach, it might be totally wrong.

Comment: use the Fourier inversion theorem : $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|x|} e^{i \omega x} dx = \frac{1}{1-i\omega}+\frac{1}{1+i\omega} = \frac{2}{1+\omega^2}$

Comment: This is definitely related to fourier transform.

Comment: The title of your book is "differential equations..." isn't a hint? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a lot of ways to prove your equality [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9402/calculating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-cos-x1x2-mathrmdx-wit?noredirect=1&lq=1). Another way (which I love) is the following. We have that $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(xt\right)}{1+t^{2}}dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ixt}+e^{-ixt}}{1+t^{2}}dt
 $$ $$=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ixt}+e^{-ixt}}{1-it}dt+\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ixt}+e^{-ixt}}{1+it}dt
 $$ $$=\frac{e^{-x}}{4i}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ixt\left(e^{x+ixt}+e^{x-ixt}\right)}{t\left(x-ixt\right)}dt+\frac{e^{-x}}{4i}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ixt\left(e^{x+ixt}+e^{x-ixt}\right)}{t\left(x+ixt\right)}dt$$ $$=\frac{e^{-x}}{4i}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ixte^{x+ixt}}{t\left(x+ixt\right)}+\frac{ixte^{x-ixt}}{t\left(x-ixt\right)}dt+\frac{e^{-x}}{4i}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ixte^{x-ixt}}{t\left(x+ixt\right)}+\frac{ixte^{x+ixt}}{t\left(x-ixt\right)}dt
 $$ so if we apply [the complex version of the Frullani's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807410/frullani-s-theorem-in-a-complex-context) to the functions $$f\left(t\right)=\frac{te^{x-t}}{x-t}
 $$ and $$g\left(t\right)=\frac{te^{x-t}}{x+t}
 $$ we get $$I=\frac{e^{-x}}{2i}\log(-1)=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-x}}
 $$ as wanted.

Comment: (+1) You should change your nickname in Marco *Frullani* ;)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It is a good idea but I think I will follow my childhood dream. I will be Max Power (Simpsons docet).

Comment: @ Marco and @JackD'Aurizio well the complex Frullani theorem isn't easier than the Fourier inversion theorem, or the residue theorem. On my side, I wonder if you can find an elementary way to solve $f(s)+f''(s)= \frac{1}{s}$ (coming from $ f(s) = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-st}}{1+t^2}dt$)