# Integral and convergence of the sinc function: $\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_\frac{1}{t}^t \frac{\sin(ax)}{x}dx $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals

I am asked to show that  $$\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_\frac{1}{t}^t \frac{\sin(ax)}{x}dx $$ converges for all real numbers $a$ and that the value of the converged integral is the same for all $a>0$.

For the first part, I want to apply a previously proven result that if $f$ is continuous and $g'$ is locally integrable on [a,b) with $\lim_{x \to b^- }g(x) = 0$ and $F(t)=\int_a^tf$ is bounded on $[a,b)$, and $g'$ has a constant sign then $\int_a^bfg$ converges. Can I use this theorem here? If we take $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $f(x)=\sin(ax)$ then clearly $F(t)$ is bounded and $g'$ has a constant sign and $g(x)$ tends to 0. But the condition of local integrability is throwing me off.

If I cannot use this theorem. How may I alternatively prove that the above integral converges? additionally, the proof that the value of the integral is the same for all positive $a$ is eluding me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assume $a>0$, $t>0$.

**Hint**. One may first perform an integration by parts,
$$
\int_{1/t}^t \frac{\sin(ax)}{x}dx =\left[\frac1{x}\cdot\frac{1- \cos(ax)}{a} \right]_{1/t}^t+\int_{1/t}^t \frac{1- \cos(ax)}{ax^2}dx
$$ giving
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{1/t}^t \frac{\sin(ax)}{x}dx =\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{1/t}^t \frac{1- \cos(ax)}{ax^2}dx\tag1
$$ the latter integrand may be extended as a *continuous* function over $[0,b]$ ($b\ge1$) satisfying
$$
\left| \frac{1- \cos(ax)}{ax^2}\right| \le  \frac{2}{ax^2}, \qquad x\ge1,
$$ the latter dominating function being integrable over $[1,\infty)$, one deduces the *convergence* of the *initial* integral.

From $(1)$, using a standard result one has

> $$
> \lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{1/t}^t \frac{\sin(ax)}{x}dx =\int_0^\infty \frac{1- \cos(ax)}{ax^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{2} ,\quad a>0.
> $$

Comment: What is the standard result you use in the last point?

Comment: @sequenceDerivative One has $\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{1/t}^t \frac{\sin(ax)}{x}dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)}{x}dx$, then with the latter integral make the change of variable $t=ax$, giving $dx/x=dt/t$ and $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)}{x}dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt$, then please have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral

Comment: Can you elaborate on the first equality? How do you arrive at $\frac{1-cos(ax)}{a}$ by integrating $sin(ax)$?

Comment: I've just used $\partial_x \left[\cos (ax)\right]=-a \sin (ax)$ giving $$\partial_x \left[\frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{a}\cos (ax)\right]=\partial_x \left[\frac{1}{a}\right] + \partial_x \left[\frac{1}{-a}\cos (ax)\right]=0+\sin (ax).$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to note that, for $a>0$, we have $$I\left(a\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(ax\right)}{x}dx=\frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{iax}-e^{-iax}}{x}dx
 $$ and now [we can use the Frullani theorem for complex parameters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807410/frullani-s-theorem-in-a-complex-context) and get $$I\left(a\right)=\frac{\log\left(\frac{ia}{-ia}\right)}{2i}=\frac{\log\left(-1\right)}{2i}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}}.$$