# Existence of $\lim_{x\to0} \int_{x}^{1 \over x} {(\cos 2r-\cos r) \over r} dr$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am trying to prove that $\lim_{x\to0} \int_{x}^{1 \over x} {(\cos 2r-\cos r) \over r} dr$ exists. Wolframalpha gives me the value ${\int_{0}^{\infty} {(\cos 2x-\cos x)\over x} dx} = -\ln2$, but I don't know where to start, based only on this information. The question is in the book "Real Analysis and Foundations" by S. Krantz.

Comment: do you only want to prove the existence of the limit or also the value $-\log(2)$?

Comment: Does $\cos 2r - \cos r = -2\sin{3r\over2}\sin{r\over 2}$ help ?

Comment: This is an example of a Frullani integral. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61828/proof-of-frullanis-theorem

Comment: Have a look at this wonderful thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807410/frullani-s-theorem-in-a-complex-context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$\lim_{x\to0} \int_{x}^{1 \over x} {(\cos 2r-\cos r) \over r} dr$

$=\lim_{x\to0} \int_{x}^{1 \over x} (\cos 2r-\cos r) d(\ln r)$

$=\lim_{x\to0} \int_{x}^{1 \over x}  \cos 2r\, d(\ln r) - \int_{x}^{1 \over x} \cos r\,d(\ln r)$

Using integration by parts should help

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\ \int_{x}^{1/x}{\cos\pars{2r} - \cos\pars{r} \over r}
> \,\dd r:\ {\large ?}}$.

\begin{align}
&\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\ \int_{x}^{1/x}{\cos\pars{2r} - \cos\pars{r} \over r}\,\dd r =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{\cos\pars{2r} - \cos\pars{r}}\ \overbrace{%
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-rt}\,\dd t}^{\ds{1 \over r}}\,\dd r
\\[5mm] = &\
\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{\expo{\pars{-t + 2\ic}r} - \expo{\pars{-t + \ic}r}}\dd r\,\dd t =
\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{-\,{1 \over -t + 2\ic} + {1 \over -t + \ic}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\left. \Re\ln\pars{t - 2\ic \over t - \ic}
\right\vert_{\ t\ =\ 0}^{\ t\ \to\ \infty} =\
\bbox[10px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{-\ln\pars{2}}}
\end{align}