# Showing that $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-ax} \frac {\sin x}{x} dx = \frac {\pi}{2} - \arctan (a)$ for any $a >0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} e^{-ax} \dfrac {\sin x}{x} dx = \dfrac {\pi}{2} - \arctan (a)$ for any $a >0$

I am really not sure how to go about doing this. I checked [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20e%5E(-x)%20sinx%20%2F%20x%20dx) and the function does not have an elementary antidericative. I do not have that many special tools (mostly just Fubini's  Theorem). My best guess is that we have to do a substitution of some kind, and maybe integration by parts. Then hopefully we will get a "known" integral. However, I don't really know in what direction to go.

Comment: Try differentiating the LHS with respect to $ a $.

Comment: Using Fubini, write $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ as $\int_0^1 f(t,x)\,dt$.

Comment: I suspect, the Laplace transform might be helpful here. Integrals from $0$ to infinity with an $x$ in a denominator can often be done that way, as the denominator's $x$ goes away after performing Laplace appropriately through $L(xf(x))=-F'(s)$

Comment: @Starfall Unfortunately we did not go over interchanging the derivative and integral.

Comment: Actually, I don't suspect, I KNOW it can be done through Laplace; looking over my notes, but I have class coming up now...

Comment: No `\displaystyle` in titles, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have
$$ \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 e^{ixt} \, dt = \frac{\sin{x}}{x}. $$
Insert this and change the order of integration with Fubini and you just have to calculate
$$ \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{dt}{a-it}. $$
You can get rid of the imaginary part by noting that
$$ \frac{1}{a-it} = \frac{a+it}{a^2+t^2} $$
and the latter term is odd, so the integral is equal to
$$ \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{a \, dt}{a^2+t^2} = \int_0^1 \frac{a \, dt}{a^2+t^2} = \arctan{(1/a)} = \operatorname{arccot}{a} = \frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan{a}. $$

Comment: Alternatively, use $${1\over2}\int_{-1}^1\cos(xt)\,dt={\sin x\over x}$$ and then (after Fubinating) integrate $$\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\cos(xt)\,dx$$ (by parts, twice).

Answer (score 4):

Let 
$$I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-ax} \frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx\qquad \text{for } a>0$$
Now differentiate with respect to $a$, 
\begin{align}
I'(a)&=-\int_0^{\infty} e^{-ax}\sin x\,dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{a^2+1} \qquad (\text{integration by parts})\\
\implies I(a)=C-\arctan a
\end{align}
From the initial integral, we know that $\lim_{a\to\infty} I(a)=0$. We can thus find the constant $C=\pi/2$.
Thus,
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-ax} \frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan a\qquad \text{for } a>0$$

Answer (score 2):

By a [fundamental property of the Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis), if $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is improperly Riemann-integrable over $\mathbb{R}^+$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}(\mathcal{L} f)(s)\,ds.$$
On the other hand 
$$ \mathcal{L}\left(e^{-ax}\sin(x)\right)(s) = \frac{1}{1+(a+s)^2} $$
is trivial by integration by parts, hence the original integral equals
$$ \int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{ds}{1+s^2} = \frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan a $$
as wanted. Here the application of Fubini's theorem is hidden in the invoked property of $\mathcal{L}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ax}\sin\left(x\right)}{x}dx=\frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{x\left(-a-i\right)}-e^{x\left(-a+i\right)}}{x}dx$$ then we can apply [the complex version of the Frullani's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807410/frullani-s-theorem-in-a-complex-context) and get the result, recalling that $$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(x\right),\, x>0.$$