# Calculating the integral $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{{(e^{-ax}-e^{-bx})}{\cos(cx)}}{x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I want to calculate:$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{{e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}}}{x}\cos(cx)\mathrm{d}x\qquad(a,b,c > 0)\tag{1}$$And I want to use:$$\frac{x}{x^2+k^2}=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xy}\cos(ky)\mathrm{d}y\tag{2}$$So, I want to think:$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{{e^{-tx}}{\cos(cx)}}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\int_t^{\infty}e^{-xy}\cos(cx)dy\tag{3}$$How can I use Fubini to chage the order of integration?

Answer (score 7):

\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\infty}\frac{{(e^{-ax}-e^{-bx})}{\cos(cx)}}{x}dx\\
=& \int_0^{\infty}\int_a^b e^{-xy}\cos(cx)\ dy dx
= \int_a^b \frac y{c^2+y^2}dy=\frac12\ln\frac{c^2+b^2}{c^2+a^2}
\end{align}

Comment: How to say $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{{e^{-tx}}{\cos(cx)}}{x}dx=\int_0^{\infty}dx\int_t^{\infty}e^{-xy}\cos{cx}dy$is integrable.(how to show (3) < ∞？)

Answer (score 4):

Using the [Frullani' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral) and denoting $f(x)=e^{-x}$
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(e^{-ax}-e^{-bx})\,\cos(cx)}{x}dx=\Re\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(e^{-ax-icx}-e^{-bx-icx})}{x}dx$$
$$=\Re\,\big(f(\infty)-f(0)\big)\ln\frac{a+ic}{b+ic}=\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{b^2+c^2}{a^2+c^2}$$

Comment: Does Frullani work for complex numbers like that?

Comment: @J.G. thank you for the good question. The generalisation of the Frullani' integral can be found here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807410/frullani-s-theorem-in-a-complex-context.  Also, for our specific case we can split the integral into two parts $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}\frac{(e^{-ax-icx}-e^{-bx-icx})}{x}dx=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(e^{-ax-icx}-e^{-x})}{x}dx-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(e^{-bx-icx}-e^{-x})}{x}dx$ and follow the way proposed by Jack D'Aurizio (second post).