# Calculate the integral where $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers ($a,b>0$)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}\cos \left (\ln \frac{1}{x}  \right )\frac{x^b-x^a}{\ln x}dx=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos \ln x}{\ln x}\left ( x^b-x^a \right )dx$$
$$t=-\ln x\Rightarrow dx=-e^{-t}dt\Rightarrow -e^t=x$$
$$\int\limits_{-\infty }^{0}\frac{\cos (-t)}{-t}\left ( e^{-tb}-e^{-ta} \right )e^tdt=-\int\limits_{-\infty }^{0}\frac{1}{t}\cdot \frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}\cdot \left ( e^{t-bt}-e^{t-at} \right )dt$$
*How do I calculate here using the Frullani formula?*

Comment: I would recommend the substitution $x=e^{-t}$. Then
$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos t}{t}\big(e^{-at}-e^{-bt}\big)e^{-t}dt=\Re\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-(a+i+1)t}-e^{-(b+i+1)t}}{t}dt$$
The Frullani integral method can be applied, but there is some specifics for complex numbers - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807410/frullani-s-theorem-in-a-complex-context

Comment: Thank you! This post helped me a lot!

Comment: See this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472101/calculating-the-integeral-int-0-infty-frace-ax-e-bx-coscxx/