# Solution of $\mathrm{sinc}(x)$ integral using Frullani integral formula gives incorrect result

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I recently came across the [Frullani integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral) and wanted to try it out by seeing if solving $\int_0^\infty{\mathrm{sinc}(x)}$ would give the familiar answer of $\pi/2$, but instead I got $-\pi/2$. I did the following:

$$
\begin{align}
  \int_0^\infty{\frac{\sin x}{x}}\ dx &= \int_0^\infty{\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2ix}}\ dx
    = \frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty{\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{x}}\ dx \\
  &= \frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty{\frac{e^{-(-i)x}-e^{-(i)x}}{x}}\ dx
\end{align}
$$

Then, taking $f(x)=e^{-x}$, $a=-i$ and $b=i$, the solution becomes

$$
\begin{align}
  \frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty{\frac{e^{-(-i)x}-e^{-(i)x}}{x}}\ dx &= \frac{1}{2i}(e^{-\infty}-e^{-0})\ln \frac{-i}{i} \\
  &= \frac{1}{2i}(-1)\ln(-1) \\
  &= -\frac{1}{2i} \cdot i\pi = -\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}
$$

I believe the error may be due to my use of $\ln(-1)=i\pi$ being invalid in this scenario, but I am not certain about this. For now, I have found two ways to "correct" the formula so that the answer gives $\pi/2$ instead of $-\pi/2$:

- Since $-1=\frac{1}{-1}$, I can deduce that $\ln(-1)=\ln((-1)^{-1})=-\ln(-1)=-i\pi$, and the two negatives cancel out. However, I'm pretty sure there's something very wrong with this and I should not be allowed to do this.
- If I instead do:
  $$
    \begin{align}
      \frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty{\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{x}}\ dx 
      &= \frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty{\frac{-(e^{-ix}-e^{ix})}{x}}\ dx \\
      &= -\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty{\frac{e^{-ix}-e^{ix}}{x}}\ dx
    \end{align}
    $$
  and then take $f(x)=e^{-x}$, $a=i$ and $b=-i$, there are again two negatives that cancel out and give $\pi/2$. This works, but it still does not answer my question of why my first attempt didn't.

Comment: In the reference you stated,  f(x)  should be a function defined for all non-negative real numbers and a and b are real too.

Comment: @Lai you're right, I read through it multiple times and still missed it, no clue how. The fact that it's so close to being correct still makes me wonder though. I did some further checking around and found https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807410/frullani-s-theorem-in-a-complex-context ; could the answers here apply to this case?

Comment: Thank you for your reference which extends the Frullani’s Theorem for complex numbers.